# Angular UI Grid: Imported Less CSS Errors after NPM Install

Tags: angularjs, less, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-grid

I installed Angular UI Grid v3.2.9 via:

```
npm install angular-ui-grid
```

We use less css in our gulp server-side build and I was pleased to find a main.less file included in the install at ~/node_modules/angular-ui-grid/less/main.less.  When I tried importing it like so from my ~/styles directory:

```
@import "../node_modules/angular-ui-grid/less/main.less";
```

I got the following Less CSS transpiler error:

```
Error: variable @bootstrapDirectory is undefined
```

That's because variable @bootstrapDirectory is defined in ~/node_modules/angular-ui-grid/less/variables.less as:

```
@bootstrapDirectory: "../../../node_modules/bootstrap";
```

and our bootstrap directory path is one level deeper and the target context of the variable is ~/node_modules/angular-ui-grid/less/.  So, I fixed this error by overriding variable @bootstrapDirectory as follows:

```
@import "../node_modules/angular-ui-grid/less/main.less";
@bootstrapDirectory: "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap";
```

Now I'm getting an error that has so far stumped me:

```
Error: #ui-grid-twbs > .btn is undefined in ...
```

.btn is a bootstrap CSS class.  The ~/node_modules/angular-ui-grid/less/bootstrap/bootstrap.less file imported by main.less looks like:

```
#ui-grid-twbs {
...
}
```

The bootstrap.less file explains:

```
 * All of the bootstrap less elements are namespaced under `#ui-grid-twbs`
 * This prevents the CSS generated using this file from conflicting with a project's
 * import of bootstrap.
```

ui-grid-twbs is referenced in the following ui-grid less files:

```
/node_modules/angular-ui-grid/less/menu.less
/node_modules/angular-ui-grid/less/cellnav/less/cellNav.less
/node_modules/angular-ui-grid/less/pagination/less/pagination.less
```

To get the grid to render without the bootstrap styles, I imported the less files included in main.less that do not reference #ui-grid-twbs like so:

```
@import "../node_modules/angular-ui-grid/less/grid.less";
@import "../node_modules/angular-ui-grid/less/header.less";
@import "../node_modules/angular-ui-grid/less/body.less";
@import "../node_modules/angular-ui-grid/less/cell.less";
@import "../node_modules/angular-ui-grid/less/footer.less";
@import "../node_modules/angular-ui-grid/less/sorting.less";
@import "../node_modules/angular-ui-grid/less/icons.less";
@import "../node_modules/angular-ui-grid/less/rtl.less";
@import "../node_modules/angular-ui-grid/less/animation.less";
@import "../node_modules/angular-ui-grid/less/elements.less";
@import "../node_modules/angular-ui-grid/less/variables.less";
```

Others have reported this problem at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/4173, but I could not understand the workaround.  ChrisWiGit wrote:

> Import does not support namespaces in less. To use namespaces all
>   files which use them have to be copied into one less file and then
>   compiled with less.

How does one apply this advice to successfully import the ui-grid less files for bootstap?

Comment: Have you found any solutions for this?

Comment: Sorry, nothing better than what I explained above.